# Is Time travel in "Star Trek: Enterprise" totally illogical?

Tags: star-trek, tv, time-travel, star-trek-enterprise

Normally Star Trek seems to based on some sort of logic, but the time travel in "Star Trek: Enterprise" seems to have no logic at all, or  am I just missing it?

Example: If they go back in time to change something it takes time until it has any effect in the future? I can't see any reason for this.

Comment: Have you _seen_ the other Star Trek series?  They're even worse.  Often [lampshaded](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) with the phrase "I hate temporal mechanics."

Comment: Let's just face it. Time Travel is illogical, period.

Comment: What was it T'Pol used to say? The Vulcan Science Ministry has decided that time travel is impossible, or something like that.

Comment: It is important to remember Star Trek's motto: "We Hate Continuity." http://atwitsendcomics.com/comics/index/23/Old-Kirk

Comment: Time travel was always way too easy in Star Trek.

Comment: @Xantec Ambassador also mentioned it.

Comment: Is there a question here aside from "let's talk"?

Comment: I quickly came to detest time travel storylines in sci-fi films and shows. When I was an early teen, it held a momentary fascination, but it seems that is perhaps the primary reason they keep using it again and again. I couldn't stand it, because the stories never held together. It's like being given a cake for your birthday. Biting into it again and again. Only to find there is no cake - only icing. Terribly sweet at first bite but quickly sickening and ultimately you can't hold it down... Which is why Enterprise was so very disappointing. A wonderful cast. Good graphics and sets. A very inte

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: I disagree, time travel is paradox, not illogical.

Comment: I think the real question should be: Is any part of Enterprise totally illogical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ST:Enterprise, time travel happened many times successfully despite the fact that the Vulcans said concept of time travel illogical..
Once Archer was taken to the 31st century in the future, which created a new timeline in which everything was destroyed including time machine.. At that time, the original timeline was intact containing the time traveling event too.
Every time-based manipulation creates a new timeline for reality to flow... it's common in many sci-fi canons.

Comment: Especially since they never settle on a constant effect of time travel.  In some cases it creates and alternate timeline that continues to exist, in some it destroys the timeline, in others it leaves the experience of the timeline intact, but the actual facts change, and don't even start on Chakotay the time pruner.  Time travel in ST fits that story's plot and cannot be taken to have any relevance to any other story.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest Multiverse theory in the real world means that any theoretical outcome is not only possible but does occur. So, if you time traveled in the real world, you would have every single possible outcome occur: in one universe, it would be destroyed, in another it would change everything, in another people could remember events from other timelines. So, the writers just choose to continue in one of the universes. Multiverse theory is fun.